# Passing `limit` `offset` options to searchkick advanced search body object

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, searchkick

I am trying to do an [Advanced search with SearchKick](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#advanced-search) on Ruby like the following:

```
Product.search(body: search_body, load: false)

def search_body
  {
    _source: true,
    query: {
      bool: {
        must: [
          {
            match: {
              name: {
                query: product.name,
                fuzziness: 'auto',
                operator: 'and',
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  }
end
```

I am now trying to pass `limit: 10, offset: 15` options to my search. Where or how do i pass the `limit: 10, offset: 15` options?

The [examples given here](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#querying) are with the `query:` option - but using the `body:` option behaves differently as it disregards any other option i pass to `.search()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use the [Elasticsearch docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-from-size.html) for advanced search.

```
def search_body
  {
    size: 10,
    from: 15,
    query: { ... }
  }
end
```